# Best way to set-up a config file to store parameters in asp net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, configuration-files

I am starting Asp Net MVC4 project and since I am comming from php development I am curious about what would it be the best way to set-up a configuration file to store parameters like system name, version and others that I might need.

Is there any guideline to do that for instance using a config file or a database query..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use web.config extensively for this type of thing.

Example

```
<appSettings>
    ....
    <add key="SearchUserResultMaxCount" value="100" />
</appSettings>
```

Code

```
public static class SearchHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the max records for resultset from db, configurable in web.config
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int SearchEntityResultMaxCount()
    {
        int count;
        Int32.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchEntityResultMaxCount"], out count);
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but those values needs to be input to a shared template. I am not going through the controller... how can I proceed? Do I have to create view and call them into the template?

Comment: This code isn't in my controller either. You can simply just write a class where each property loads it's default value from the config. That's exactly what this helper is doing for me. I can refer to `SearchHelper.SearchEntityResultMaxCount` from anywhere now. In your case, just make it a property instead of a method.